# Can not execute jar of ortools project, Loader.loadNativeLibraries() errors

Tags: java, or-tools

After mvn install to generate jar. Can not Loader.loadNativeLibraries() on windows.

The version of ortools is 9.0.9048. I used it on windows.
I added the following two jar to the project and I added them as the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) said.

[image]

Then the two jar is in here of the IDEA.

[image]

The pom file is the following:

[image]

Then I can run the program normally in IDEA. But when I mvn install to generate the jar file and run the jar by 'java -jar jarfile.jar', it errors as:

[image]

It said java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /BOOT-INF/lib/ortools-win32-9.0.jar!/win32-x86-64/, but when I open the jar in winrar, it exists.

[image]

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example of Mac version.

You need two jars when using ortools in Java actually, `ortools-java-9.0.9048.jar` and `ortools-darwin-x86-64-9.0.9048.jar`. The two jar is unzipped from the official file and they are in the main directory.

`ortools-java-9.0.9048.jar` is the algorithm package which you do not need to care to much. Adding dependency to your program is all of you need to do.

The key is the `ortools-darwin-x86-64-9.0.9048.jar`. The following code is to read this jar to finally call the algorithm in `ortools-java-9.0.9048.jar`:

```
import com.google.ortools.Loader;
Loader.loadNativeLibraries();
```

It usually works well in IDEA. But when you package the code to a jar file, error happens because of `Loader.loadNativeLibraries();` can not find the file in the `ortools-darwin-x86-64-9.0.9048.jar`.

The solution is to unzip `ortools-darwin-x86-64-9.0.9048.jar` and get the absolute path of `libjniortools.dylib`(if you are using linux, it will be a file similar as `libjniortools.so` and a file similar as `libjniortools.dll` in Windows). And using the following code instead of `Loader.loadNativeLibraries();`

```
System.load("Absolute path/libjniortools.dylib");
```

It will work after you package your code by this method.

Comment: thanks, it work perfect on my macos.

Comment: Thank you it worked. FYI for windows the file name was 'jniortools.dll'. Found the file from my own build jar (Extracted it)

Answer (score 0):

The official artifacts are:
groupe: com.google.ortools, artifact: ortools-java

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.ortools/ortools-java/9.0.9048/jar

Comment: I can not import com.google.ortools if adding the link's dependency to the pom file.

Comment: well, did you know last maven install plugin 3.0.0-M1 can read the pom.xml inside the archive ? I'm not sure renaming like you did the group and artifact id will work...
see https://github.com/or-tools/java_or-tools

Comment: It is correct in pom file, meaning that the program can download the given dependency. But the ortools can not import ortools in code.

Comment: Solved by using System.load("xxx\\jniortools.dll"), jniortools.dll comes from one of the ortools jars.

Answer (score -1):

For macOS, you can try this code, similar like @Muz solution

```java
public static void loadOrToolLibrary() {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name", "generic").toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
        if (os.equals("mac os x")) { // only for MAC local
            File file = new File("src/main/resources/macosLocal/libjniortools.dylib");
            String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            System.load(absolutePath);
        } else {
            Loader.loadNativeLibraries();
        }
    }
```